# Kotlin getter setter without field

Tags: properties, kotlin, field

I would like to create a getter and setter without a field. Currently I have this function:

```
/** Only the color component will be considered, alpha has no effect */ 
fun setCircleColor(@ColorInt color : Int){
    circlePaint.color = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, circlePaint.alpha)
}
```

Ideally I would like to have something like this

```
circleColor: @ColorInt Int 
  get(){
    return circlePaint.color
  set(value){
    circlePaint.color = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, circlePaint.alpha)
  }
```

As you can see, I don't want to store circleColor in a var, yet be able to call

`myView.color = 0xFFaaaaaa` 
instead of `myView.setColor(0xFFaaaaaa)`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to just implement it the way you're intending to do it:

```
var circleColor: Int
    @ColorInt get() = circlePaint.color
    set(@ColorInt color) {
        circlePaint.color = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, circlePaint.alpha)
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it a waste of memory to have an unused circleColor Int?